# CSS Styles are not reflected in the HTML

Tags: html, css

I have implemented the CSS Styles in styles.css and used that file in the ExternalCSSStyles.html. The file contents are as below:
styles.css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
h1 {
    color:fuchsia;
    font-family:verdana;
    font-size:300%;

}
p  {
    color:maroon;
    font-family:courier;
    font-size:160%;
}
</style>
</head>
</html>
```

The ExternalCSSStyles.html is as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>This is a heading</h1>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

The output displayed is as below:
This is a heading(black in color)

This is a paragraph.(maroon in color)

But If i modify the ExternalCSSStyles.hmtl to make it Internal CSS Styling as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
h1 {
    color:fuchsia;
    font-family:verdana;
    font-size:300%;

}
p  {
    color:maroon;
    font-family:courier;
    font-size:160%;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>This is a heading</h1>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Then the output is as below:
This is a heading(fushia in color)

This is a paragraph.(maroon in color)

My Question is why the header is not getting effected as per the style provided in the styles.css?
Kindly help me to figure out this problem.

Comment: html body style tags are not required in .css file

Comment: I think that you have place <!doctype> and html tags in external css file, the external css file shouldnt include any tags it should look like         h1 {
    color:fuchsia;
    font-family:verdana;
    font-size:300%;

}
p  {
    color:maroon;
    font-family:courier;
    font-size:160%;
}

Comment: should be like this [style.css](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Qn1FY7qn)

Answer (score 6):

You are adding `styles.css` but `styles.css` must **not** contain any `html` tags so remove all html tags from styles.css like

```css
h1 {
    color:fuchsia;
    font-family:verdana;
    font-size:300%;

}
p  {
    color:maroon;
    font-family:courier;
    font-size:160%;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
```

and test your page it will work fine..